# How to filter inputs by parent node, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with filtering inputs.

I have partial view which include sth like this:

```
<div class="editor">
<div class="demand-editor-label editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorkGroupID) @Model.WorkTypeD</div>
<div class="default-editor-field">
    <div style="max-height:100px; overflow:auto;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;padding:3px; width: 98% !important; max-width:590px" id="@string.Format("uiDivWorkGroup{0}",Model.WorkTypeD)">  
        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.WorkGroupID, x => x.WorkGroupList, x => x.Key, x => x.Value, x => x.SelectedWorkGroups, new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 2))   
    </div>                             
</div>
```

I execute it in my view like this:

```
<div id="uiDivWorkGroupMainNn" style="padding-top: 5px; clear: both">                
                     @Html.PartialFor(model => model, MVC.Components.Views.Partial.WorkGroupView)
                </div>

<div id="uiDivWorkGroupMainSn" style="padding-top: 5px; clear: both">
                    @Html.PartialFor(model => model, MVC.Components.Views.Partial.WorkGroupView)
                </div>

<div id="uiDivWorkGroupMainWn" style="padding-top: 5px; clear: both"> 
                    @Html.PartialFor(model => model, MVC.Components.Views.Partial.WorkGroupView)
                </div>
```

There is three different groups that using this partialview.

There is output:

```
<div id="uiDivWorkGroupMainNn" style="padding-top: 5px; clear: both;">
<div class="editor">
    <div class="demand-editor-label editor-label"><label for="WorkGroupID">Work group</label> Nn</div>
    <div class="default-editor-field">
        <div id="uiDivWorkGroupNn" style="border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 3px; width: 98% !important; overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; max-width: 590px;">  
            <table cellSpacing="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <input name="WorkGroupID" id="WorkGroupID12" type="checkbox" value="1034">
            <label for="WorkGroupID12">Emergency [nN]</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input name="WorkGroupID" id="WorkGroupID13" type="checkbox" value="1021">
            <label for="WorkGroupID13">Cable nN</label>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr></tbody></table>   
        </div>                             
    </div>
</div>
<br>


</div>
<div id="uiDivWorkGroupMainWn" style="padding-top: 5px; clear: both;">
<div class="editor">
        <div class="demand-editor-label editor-label"><label for="WorkGroupID">Grupa prac</label> Wn</div>
        <div class="default-editor-field">
            <div id="uiDivWorkGroupWn" style="border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 3px; width: 98% !important; overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; max-width: 590px;">
<table cellSpacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <input name="WorkGroupID" id="WorkGroupID12" type="checkbox" value="1014">
                <label for="WorkGroupID15">Emergency [Wn]</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input name="WorkGroupID" id="WorkGroupID13" type="checkbox" value="1029">
                <label for="WorkGroupID16">Call Wn</label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr></tbody></table>   
            </div>                             
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    </div>
```

Finally I want to use sth like this:

```
$('input[name|="WorkGroupID"]').change(some function1);
$('input[name|="WorkGroupID"]').change(some function2);
$('input[name|="WorkGroupID"]').change(some function3);
```

Unfortunately it collects all inputs and imposes on them 1-3function calls on *change event* but I want to collect them only from one group and apply them specific function. My first thought was to filter group of inputs by **div** parent which is  for example **uiDivWorkGroupMainWn** but don't know how to do it. If it's even possible. I try sth like this but it doesn't work. I've read about .filter function but I don't know how to use it in this specific situation.

```
$('input[name|="WorkGroupID"]').parent("#uiDivWorkGroupMainNn").change(some function);
```

At this moment I'm not good at JS, so that's why I'm writing here.

Comment: Please show the relevant generated HTML created by the asp.net script, not the script itself.

Comment: considering you saying "filtering by parent" could be like - $('#uiDivWorkGroupMainNn input[name|="WorkGroupID"]').change(some function); would this work?

Comment: @David Thomas I've added output. I hope so it'll help.

Comment: _$(selector, context)_: `$('input[name|="WorkGroupID"]', '#uiDivWorkGroupMainNn')`

Comment: @shershen It helped! Thanks! How make this post answered? Should I answer myself or edit post and at the end write that your post solved my problem?

Comment: @vindemi, good that it worked! NP man, don't bother )

Comment: I put together a solution that I thought would help, but I think it was solving a problem you weren't having, so I'm not posting it as an answer; but, if it's of any help: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rygp6L2q/).